# Python и потокобезопасность

Tags: python, c, многопоточность

В cpython используется GIL, чтобы запретить параллельное выполнение потоков, так как cpython непотокобезопасный.
Другие языки разве являются потокобезопасными? Если да, то можете пожалуйста поподробнее расписать потокобезопасность применительно к cpython и к какому-нибудь другому потокобезопасному языку.

Comment: GIL в CPython для того, чтобы облегчить механизм управления памятью и сделать проще интероперабельность с C.

Answer (score 2):

> Другие языки разве являются потокобезопасными?

Подавляющая часть языков программирования создавалась, исходя из ОДНОпоточной модели. В этих языках просто нет понятия "процесс" или "поток". Поэтому говорить о том, опасен ли данный язык, или нет - просто не имеет смысла. Параллелизм в эти языки привносится "через задний проход" - с помощью системных вызовов типа *fork()* или библиотек типа *pthread*. Ни то, ни другое не является элементом языка.

Поэтому, рассуждая про "потокобезопасность" надо понимать, что это свойство библиотеки(!) функций и подпрограмм, которые Вы используете в своей программе.

Например, если смотреть *man* по функциям из стандартной библиотеки "С" для Linux, то там явно отмечены функции, не являющиеся потокобезопасными. Постарайтесь их не использовать в многопоточной программе и всё будет - ОК!

Особо стоит остановиться на языках, в которых параллельность выполнения заложена в сам язык. Из старых - "Ада", из новых - "Rust", "Go". Если Вас реально беспокоит проблема надёжности параллельных программ - используйте эти языки и жизнь не будет казаться такой мрачной!

Comment: Можно ли утверждать, что главное свойство любого «потокобезопасного» языка — это явно описанная модель памяти?

Comment: @Arhad Ну, разумеется - работа с памятью должна быть безопасной! Но я не думаю, что это - единственное свойство языков со встроенной поддержкой многопоточности. В порядке важности (IMHO): 1) сохранность данных при одновременном доступе 2) Средства взаимодействия между потоками 3) Отслеживание таймаутов и зависаний потоков 4) Планировщик приоритетов 5) ...